# If $f'(x)=[f(x)]^2 \enspace \forall x \ in \mathbb{R}$ and $f(0)=0$ then $f=0$ everywhere.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity

**Problem**

Let $f:\mathbb{R}→\mathbb{R}$
be a differentiable function such that $f(0)=0$ and $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \enspace f′(x)=[f(x)]^2.$

**My Process**

I want to solve this question with analysis arguments, not simply ODE. This question is in the integral chapter so maybe we should use that.

Anyways. A method that would work would be to show that as $f$ is continuous, the set of points where $f \neq 0$ is open. If we then show that this set is also closed, it would have to be the empty set since as $f(0)=0$, it can not be $\mathbb{R}$. The thing is I cant see how to show this.

Also, is there another way, actually using integrals?

Comment: Although Barry Cipra's solution in the linked answer uses the mean value theorem, if you want a solution using integrals you can apply the MVT's cousin the fundamental theorem of calculus. The stated relation between $f'$ and $f$ gives you $$f(x) = \int_0^x f(t)^2 \, dt.$$ You can show this fails for small $x$.